# What are the location of the following arguments in the stack assemblyx86

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64

For this assume that we are using Windows (so that the first 5 arguments of a function are in registers and the rest are pushed on the stack in reverse order)

Consider the following function:

```
// int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h, int i)
    // {
    //   int x, y, z;
    //   x = g+1;
    //   y = h+1;
    //   z = i+1;
    // return x+y+z;
    // }
```

on assembly the function starts like this:

```
foo: 
pushq   %rbp 
movq    %rsp, %rbp

subq    $32,%rsp    #allocate space for %rbx plus three 4-byte local variables, keeping 16-byte alignment
 ...
```

(%rbx is a callee register and will be pushed into the stack so we allocate more space by decrementing %rsp)

My question is given this information? what are the location (as offsets of %rbp) of ints e,f,g,h,i

According to my professor:

```
# e is at %rbp + 48   (unused in this function) 
# f is at %rbp + 56   (unused in this function)
# g is at %rbp + 64      
# h is at %rbp + 72
# i is at %rbp + 80
```

But I don't really understand the logic.

To me, it feels like here there is some confusion between %rsp and %rbp.
In my opinion the stack looks more like this:

[image: stack]

(the addresses as offsets of %rbp are on the picture)

Am I missing something?

Comment: The Windows' ABI requires a shadow/home space. While the first four args are passed in the registers, an equivalent amount of space is made on the stack by the caller. Thus it's like all the args were on the stack (when it comes to their addresses).

Comment: Also don't forget that WinABI requires RSP be 16-bytes aligned before CALL. The diagram  **Stack layout when Fastmode=Yes** at https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/winabi.htm#WinABI might help.